# Show and update date with correct format

Tags: laravel

I have a edit page that shows a date and is possible to change the date and edit it.

I want to show the date in this format "25-08-18 - 15:30" if the date already is stored in DB. So I have this field:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
        <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"
               name="date" value="{{!empty($post->date) ? $post->date->formatLocalized('j-m-y - H:i') : ''}}"
               class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY"/><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-primary"
               aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But like that it shows "j-m-y - H:i" in the input field value. Do you know why?

Like this:

```
value="{{!empty($post->date)
            ? $post->date->toDateTimeString()
            : ''
        }}
```

it shows the seconds "2018-08-25 15:30:00" but it should show only "2018-08-25 15:30".

---

Then to validate is used:

```
'date' => 'nullable|date_format:"j-m-y - H:i"',
```

And to update is used:

```
     $post->date = (isset($request->date)) ?
 Carbon::createFromFormat('j-m-y - H:i', $request->date) : null;
```

Comment: In blade try something like this {{ date("Y-m-d H:i", $post->date) }}

Answer (score 1):

```
value="{{!empty($post->date)
            ? substr($post->date->toDateTimeString(),0,-2)
            : ''
        }}
```

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears that the date has a invalid format when the user clicks in the update button.

Comment: did you mean format like this     $post->date->formatLocalized('Y-m-d  - H:i')

Answer (score 1):

`format` and `formatLocalized` are not the same and are not interchangeable.

[formatLocalized()](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization) uses [strrftime()](http://www.php.net/strftime) under the hood and is used for formatting local time/date according to locale settings and does not accept the same formatting string/characters as the `format()` method.

You should be able to achieve what you're after by changing:

```
$post->date->formatLocalized('j-m-y - H:i')
```

to:

```
$post->date->format('j-m-y - H:i')
```